# How to query jsonb value in where clause?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use PostgreSQL with Sequelize. I have one `templates` table that has one column named `location` and its type is JSONB.

`userLocationIds` is an array of Location. I wrote a function that want to filter the template as its Location that the value of it should be included `userLocationIds`.

But when I run  get empty array. How can I solve it?

This is my code:

```
export const getList = async (oId, userId) => {
  const userLocationIds = await UserLocation.findAll({
    where: { userId: userId},
    attributes:["locationId"]
  }).map((location) => {
    return location.locationId
  })
  
  const templatesList = await Templates.findAll({
    where: { oId , location: { [Op.in]: userLocationIds }},
  })
  return templatesList
}
```

my template is like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "templateName": "test",
        "orgId": "7549",
        "location": [
            1,
            316,
            317
        ],
        "items": null,
        "templateType": "cxxred",
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "templateName": "test2",
        "orgId": "7549",
        "location": [
            2
            316,
            327
        ],
        "items": null,
        "templateType": "cxxred",
        
    }]
```

Comment: Can you show in your post a content of `location.locationId`?

Comment: userLocationIds is like [1,11,16] actually location.locationId each time return one id.

Comment: Show an example of a content in JSONB `location` as a JSON

Comment: it is like "location": [
            1,
            316,
            317
        ]

Comment: `JSONB` data type does not support `IN` operator in PostgreSQL

Comment: so how can I filter that , do you have any solution?

Comment: You can try to use `sequelize,where` and sequeilize.col` to imprement something like this: `'[1,2,3]'::jsonb @> '[2,3]'::jsonb`